# Is the path of a charge in magnetic field uniquely determined by two points?

Tags: magnetic-fields

My questions is as the title suggests, if I know two points a charge passes in a magnetic field, will that correspond to one unique path?

I know that a starting point and velocity gives me one unique path but this one doesn't seem as obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. For example, consider particle moving in a circle positioned horizontally. There are two paths for the particle to get from the top to the bottom point of the circle.